# webClient.OpenRead Image extension webp problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I have a problem.

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
Image img1 = Image.FromStream(webClient.OpenRead("https://i4.hurimg.com/i/hurriyet/75/1110x740/5b0e5ddabf49c21958da2d8a.jpg"));
```

My code above works. Image extension jpg,png,gif

Extension does not work when webp:

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
Image img1 = Image.FromStream(webClient.OpenRead("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1f/aa/9d/1faa9d339378d2f1cf5307da05dd0aff.webp"));
```

What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: `webp` is not a supported image format for the `Image` class or the `Bitmap` class. You might need to convert using unsafe native methods or find a library that does this for you.

Comment: You may also use the HTML Canvas drawImage method for this, basically passing the string location of your webp image file.: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp